# Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null

Tags: java, eclipse, input, path, jgrasp

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at com.game.src.gfx.BufferedImageLoader.loadImage(BufferedImageLoader.java:15)
at com.game.src.main.Game.init(Game.java:43)
at com.game.src.main.Game.run(Game.java:81)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my full error, I had a very basic but running game that I created in Eclipse. I tried to open the Game.java file in JGrasp to see if i could run it, because that is the program we use at my school. When I tried running in JGrasp, it didn't work, so I tried running it in eclipse again, and this error came up. This is the part of my Game.java that calls the BufferedImageLoader which is where the error is coming from.

```
public void init() throws IOException{
    requestFocus();
    BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();

    spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("SpriteSheet.png");  

    SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(spriteSheet);
    im = new ImageManager(ss);

    p = new Player(5 * TILE, 10 * TILE, im, im.playeru);

    this.addKeyListener(p);
    BufferedImage limage = loader.loadImage("/level1.png");
    l1 = new Level(limage);


}
```

My game class creates a new BufferedImageLoader instance called loader and sets the constructor as ("SpriteSheet.png") which is the constructor for my BufferedImageLoader class in eclipse.

The class BufferedImageLoader is as follows

```
package com.game.src.gfx;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class BufferedImageLoader {

private BufferedImage image;


public BufferedImage loadImage(String path) throws IOException{

    image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
    return image;


}


}
```

I don't know why it stopped working, and I searched around a decent amount, If you could help me it would be REALLY appreciated!
If you need any more code or information, don't hesitate to ask,
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your image file ("SpriteSheet.png") should be in the same package as your `BufferedImageLoader` class.

Check the documentation on how to specify the path - [`public URL getResource(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).